Unused keyword parameter: n_jobs during cuML estimator initialization
i am facing this issue while compare models with use_gpu = True in pycaret
can any one hwlp regarding this
models_include = ['xgboost','catboost','lr' ,'lasso' ,'ridge','knn']
all_models = exp1.compare_models(include = models_include)
Model   MAE MSE RMSE    R2  RMSLE   MAPE    TT (Sec)

xgboost Extreme Gradient Boosting   11.6016 1860.8398   33.4469 0.6999  0.9077  1.0427  0.6320
catboost    CatBoost Regressor  11.8242 2076.3099   34.9457 0.6769  1.0028  1.0757  3.0180
[I] [04:49:18.884726] Unused keyword parameter: n_jobs during cuML estimator initialization
[I] [04:49:20.410134] Unused keyword parameter: n_jobs during cuML estimator initialization
